# Incorrect Linking with minitoc and hyperref

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, bookmarks, minitoc

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

%font
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

%change TOC header
\addto\captionsenglish{% Replace "english" with the language you use
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}%
    {Table of Contents}%
}

%remove numbering from TOC
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

%omit subsections and lower levels from base TOC
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

%make TOC headers links, including minitoc subsections
\usepackage[bookmarks,bookmarksopen,bookmarksdepth=2]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue
}


%mini TOCs in each section
\usepackage{minitoc}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\textbf{Title}
\end{center}
\dosecttoc
\tableofcontents
\newpage 

\section{Sect1}
\secttoc
\subsection{Sub1}
Stuff
\newpage 
\section{Sect2}
\secttoc
\subsection{Sub2}
Stuff2
\newpage 
\section{Test}
\end{document}
```

This gives me the following .pdf's first page:

[image]

If you were to try to click the links, you'll notice that none of them go to the intended pages. Why is this?

Another point of concern is the bookmark structure it has:

[image]

So, for some reason, it thinks that Sect2 is a `subsubsection` of Sect1, which is obviously not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\usepackage{minitoc}` before `\usepackage{hyperref}`, which should be the last package in almost any case (Exceptions are `cleveref` and `glossaries`), but it's no particular `minitoc` related issue -- it's valid for many packages dealing with `ToC` and counters.

`minitoc` does some changes to ToC and counters which must be made known to `hyperref`.

```
\documentclass{article}

%font
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

%change TOC header
\addto\captionsenglish{% Replace "english" with the language you use
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}%
    {Table of Contents}%
}

%remove numbering from TOC
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

%omit subsections and lower levels from base TOC
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
%mini TOCs in each section
\usepackage{minitoc}

%make TOC headers links, including minitoc subsections

\usepackage[bookmarks,bookmarksopen,bookmarksdepth=2]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue
}





\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\textbf{Title}
\end{center}
\dosecttoc
\tableofcontents
\newpage 

\section{Sect1}
\secttoc
\subsection{Sub1}
Stuff
\newpage 
\section{Sect2}
\secttoc
\subsection{Sub2}
Stuff2
\newpage 
\section{Test}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Clarinetist: It's a common 'error' ;-)