# Changing the mini toc header title "Contents"

Tags: table-of-contents, minitoc

Follow-up to [Incorrect Linking with minitoc and hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278755/incorrect-linking-with-minitoc-and-hyperref).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

%font
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

%change TOC header
\addto\captionsenglish{% Replace "english" with the language you use
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}%
    {Table of Contents}%
}

%remove numbering from TOC
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

%omit subsections and lower levels from base TOC
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
%mini TOCs in each section
\usepackage{minitoc}

%make TOC headers links, including minitoc subsections

\usepackage[bookmarks,bookmarksopen,bookmarksdepth=2]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\textbf{Title}
\end{center}
\dosecttoc
\tableofcontents
\newpage 

\section{Sect1}
\secttoc
\subsection{Sub1}
Stuff
\newpage 
\section{Sect2}
\secttoc
\subsection{Sub2}
Stuff2
\newpage 
\section{Test}
\end{document}
```

I understand that every time I do `secttoc`, I get a section table of contents. Is there any way I can change the title of this section TOC from "Contents" to "Section Contents," i.e., the part in blue below?

[image]

Comment: `\mtcsettitle{secttoc}{Section Contents}` ;-)

Comment: I suggest to change the title and the tag, since this is not related to the `titletoc` package and as of now misleading

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I wouldn't know what to change it to, to be honest. I haven't even heard of `mtcsettitle` before today.

Comment: See page 42 of the current manual (there has been a package update some months ago) (And I have to admit, that it is a little bit hard to read that manual ;-)). And I changed the title and tags as a proposition

Comment: Related question with an accepted answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/312979/92041

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The titles of the `sub`-tocs are set with

```
\mtcsettitle{subtoctype}{foo}
```

where `subtoctype` is `parttoc` or `secttoc` for example and `foo` is the 'arbitrary' toc title.

```
\documentclass{article}

%font
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

%change TOC header
\addto\captionsenglish{% Replace "english" with the language you use
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}%
    {Table of Contents}%
}

%remove numbering from TOC
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

%omit subsections and lower levels from base TOC
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
%mini TOCs in each section
\usepackage{minitoc}

%make TOC headers links, including minitoc subsections

\usepackage[bookmarks,bookmarksopen,bookmarksdepth=2]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue
}

\mtcsettitle{secttoc}{Section Contents}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\textbf{Title}
\end{center}
\dosecttoc
\tableofcontents
\newpage 

\section{Sect1}
\secttoc
\subsection{Sub1}
Stuff
\newpage 
\section{Sect2}
\secttoc
\subsection{Sub2}
Stuff2
\newpage 
\section{Test}
\end{document}
```