# Removing/Renaming the title of minitoc

Tags: table-of-contents, minitoc

For `minitoc` package, the ToC title can be changed through the command `\stctitle`. However, for the following MWE, I found the same ToC title "Contents" without change.

So, what is wrong or missing?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum,minitoc}


\addto{\captionsenglish}{%
\renewcommand{\stctitle}{Another Title}
}

\begin{document}
\dominitoc

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\minitoc

\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[1-20]
\section{Section 2}
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've deleted the `scrbook` tag -- it's not related

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`\minitoc` is used for a chapter - wise `ToC`, so `\mtctitle` must be changed, not `\stctitle` (which is for section-wise ToC) (section toc title)

I doubt however that `minitoc` and `KOMA` is a good combination, therefore I switched to `book` instead of `scrbook` class.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{minitoc}


\addto{\captionsenglish}{% Making babel aware of special titles
  \renewcommand{\mtctitle}{Another Title}
}

\begin{document}
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\minitoc

\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[1-20]
\section{Section 2}
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your help to answer my clumsy question. Out of curiosity, I found the toc section entries are indented one level to the right, how can I left align the section entries to the left?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou: `\mtcsetoffset{minitoc}{some value}` would be one possibility

Comment: Before `\begin{document}` , I added `\mtcsetoffset{minitoc}{0pt}` , but I got the same result. Did I make it wrong?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou: That's the default. It's a little bit tricky. Try `-4em` instead of `0pt`, but it will shift the whole toc only the left, including the page numbers.

Comment: Ohh, I see. I greatly appreciate your informative help.

Comment: It's possible to trick with `\mtcindent`, but I did not receive convincing results so far

Comment: For a reference, it seems the `\captionsenglish` part has to be adjusted in case someone is using another language (see your `minitoc` settings, e.g. `\usepackage[czech]{minitoc}`). I changed mine to `\addto{\captionsczech}{ \renewcommand{\mtctitle}{Nový název}}`